# Python: how to get size of all objects in current namespace?

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, size, introspection

I have some code that I am running from my own package and the program is using a lot more memory (60GB) than it should be. How can I print the size of all objects (in bytes) in the current namespace in order to attempt to work out where this memory is being used?

I attempted something like

```
from pympler import asizeof

for objname in dir():
    print(asizeof.asizeof(thing)/1024) # print size in kb
```

But it doesn't work as it just prints the size of the string containing the name of the object in the namespace. Is there a way to get an object reference to everything in the namespace in order to use this method or is there a better method for working out what is using the memory?

Comment: Yes, `dir()` produces *just the names* as strings. Use `globals()` and `locals()` to get the namespace as a dictionary so you can access the objects themselves, not the names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dir()` returns only the names present in the local scope. Use the [`locals()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to get the local scope as a dictionary:

```
for obj in locals().values():
    print(asizeof.asizeof(obj) / 1024)
```

Note that outside of functions, `locals()` is the same mapping as [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

If `asizeof()` is in the dictionary, you want to filter it out:

```
for name, obj in locals().items():
    if name != 'asizeof':
        print(asizeof.asizeof(obj) / 1024)
```

`dir()` without arguments is functionally equivalent to `sorted(locals())` (a sorted list of the keys of the local namespace).

Comment: I appear to get a recursion issue when I run this. I imagine due to asizeof running on itself, is there a simple way to remove this from the dict created by locals()?

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist: iterate over the `dict.items()` name-value pairs so you can filter it out. Alternatively, use `if obj is not asizeof:`.

Comment: I had a number of temporary variables referencing asizeof so a more general method to filter these out was simply a try except statement.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist: or the `if obj is not asizeof:`, as that tests the identity of the object, not the name.

Comment: The largest objects in locals() is only 1.27MB so I think whatever is using the memory doesn't have a reference to it in the namespace. I'm running the code from a jupyter notebook and the memory usage clears when the kernel is restarted.

Comment: Does `import gc; gc.collect()` help?

Comment: No, it doesn't, using the above comment by @Duncan I can see that a load of functions are being created so I have an idea what it might be.

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer to use a standard library and also want them sorted by size:

```
import sys
objects=[]
for name,obj in locals().items():
   objects.append([name,sys.getsizeof(obj)])
sorted(objects,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

Comment: I seem to get the `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. So, I put all my variables in a namespace `ns`, and replaced `locals()` with `ns`. This seemed to work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gc.get_objects()` to just fetch all objects tracked by the collector, not just those in a specific namespace. I'd start by using it to count the number of instances of each type as that might give you some clues in itself.

```
from collections import Counter
import gc

c = Counter(type(o) for o in gc.get_objects())
print(c.most_common(20))
```

Then you might drill down to find the size of any likely suspects.

Comment: true. I've updated it. You still have to be careful to avoid infinite loops but I've found `get_objects()` a useful starting point for memory leaks in the past.